# SWT Canvas PaintListener() getting invoked wrongly

Tags: java, canvas, swt, listener, paint

I have the following code:

```
cnvs.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        e.gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getImageData().width,
                       img.getImageData().height, 0, 0,
                   cnvs.getSize().x, cnvs.getSize().y);
        if (curImg >= 0 && curImg < IMG_COUNT - 1) curImg++;
        else curImg=0;
    }
});
```

Where I display a sequence of Images which are invoked by cnvs.redraw() at regular time intervals. The images display at specified time intervals, but anytime I move a window over the canvas or minimize the UI and maximize it again, the paint listener is invoked and draws the next image. I don't observe this behavior on Linux/Mac OS but only on windows. I don't know whats wrong !

The cnvs is defined this way

```
 cnvs = new Canvas(customContainer, SWT.NONE);
```

I have even tried using

`cnvs = new Canvas(customContainer,SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED|SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE);`

but it doesn't work !

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing, everything works just fine.

> "Classes which implement this interface provide methods that deal with
>   the events that are generated when the control needs to be painted."

From the JavaDoc (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FPaintListener.html).

If you resize or move the window, the canvas may need to be redrawn (e.g. when the window becomes so small that a part of the canvas is hidden).

Since SWT uses the native components, this may behave different on different OSes

Comment: Well, my window is not resizable. What is the reason the paint listener is behaving this way only on windows? Is there a way to avoid this behaviour or any alternative ?

Comment: Well, but since you can move it, it will be redrawn from the OS. Your design looks a little bit odd, this is not what the listener is for. Why don't you extract the draw stuff in a new method and call it periodly? And, to the windows question: SWT uses the native OS components.

Comment: @Abbas As the answer says the OS may ask you to paint the control at any time, you cannot rely on it just being called when you use redraw. The paint behavior will vary significantly between different OSs.

Comment: As indicated,I think I need to control the draw image inside the paintControl since it's getting invoked even when redraw is not called. Strange how it works perfectly on Linux and Mac.

Comment: You can call redraw() on your own

Comment: I am calling redraw() at the right time but as @greg-449 pointed out, I can't just rely on that.